# pegar header y footer en varias paginas

Tags: php, html5

Hola comunidad hoy tengo un problema, estoy optimizando la web de mi negocio para que sea mas fácil de trabajar y se me ocurrio la idea de incluir en todas las paginas un header importandolo desde el documento **html** el problema esta en que no se como hacerlo y busco y rebusco pero ninguna forma me funciona, intente con iframe pero me comentarón que no es lo correcto entonces quedo en na situación incomoda, alguien sabe que hacer en estos caso ?

Comment: solo incluyelo con un include.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes incluir tu documento usando `include`

Pones en el documento

```
<?php
include ('header.html');
?>
```

asi incluiras todo lo que tenga tu documento

Comment: Lo hice pero el problema es que no lo acepta por eso me confunde eso el index debe ser .php ?

Comment: eso depende la extension que contenga tu archivo, si es `.php`, o `.html`

Answer (score 0):

Tan simple como mascar chicle, solo crea dos archivos html. Uno llamado `header.html` y otro `footer.html`.
En el archivo `header.html` incluirás todo el código que quieres que vaya en la cabecera de la pagina.
Y en el archivo `footer.html` incluirás todo el código que quieres que vaya en el pie de pagina.
Y tal como lo dice Edwin, lo incluirás mediante php.

Digamos que este es el código de tu pagina web:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titulo de pagina</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "header.html";
?>
// Todo el contenido de la pagina... etc...
<?php
include "footer.html";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mi duda en general esta en si al agregar esto el documento debe estar en .php o .html

Comment: Eso depende de ti, pues es recomendable en formato .php por si deseas añadir funciones php en el header o footer

Comment: No me deja añadirlo cuando es un index.html

Comment: cambialo a index.php o cambia la configuración de tu htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Si lo manejas desde un controlador (MVC), puedes llamarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->load->view("ruta_de_la_vista/archivo.html");
```

Dentro del archivo `HTML` te recomendaría que solo tengas el código que necesitas, ya que, así debe funcionar *estructuradamente*.

Si es .php solo debes pondrías sin la extención:

```
$this->load->view("ruta_de_la_vista/archivo");
```